# Sprites color changes as the distance increases

Tags: c#, colors, unity-game-engine, sprite

I looking for the programming logic behind the following scenario: I'm trying to change the color of sprites from Blue -> Red as they are get more and more far away from a particular point on space.

So, as the sprite as at a further distance from a particular point in screen, the color of their SprriteRenderer should change accordingly.

This is what I've done right now:

```
        if (distanceBetweemCenterAndSprites > 10.0F)
        {
            sprites[pos]
               .GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>()
               .color = new Color(1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
        }
```

The code is simply calculates the distance between the centre (the point) and the sprites. If Distance > 10.0F, the color of all the sprites become red. What I want is a progressive change in color (from Blue -> Red) but I can't seem to find a logic to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ColorShifter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MinDistance = 1f;
    public float MaxDistance = 10f;

    public Transform Target;
    protected SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer;

    protected void Awake()
    {
        SpriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    protected void Update()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.transform.position);
        var ratio = Mathf.Clamp01((distance - MinDistance) / (MaxDistance - MinDistance));
        var inverseRatio = 1f - ratio;
        SpriteRenderer.color = new Color(ratio * ratio, 0f, inverseRatio * inverseRatio);
    }
}
```

Assign this script to a sprite and don't forget to set `Target`.

This is a basic color interpolation. This topic can get really tough depending on how deep you want to dive. Search for color interpolation techniques if you think it won't be enough. But I hope this code gives some idea.